# How to handle reference in mobx?

Tags: mobx

For example I have Payments and have User. It's Many-to-one relationship. But I don't want to have Payments as nested properties of User.

In redux I would live an ID.

```
//redux
const state = {
  users = [{
    id: 232,
    payments: [123]
  }]
  payments: [{
    id: 123,
    user: 232
  }]
}
```

or something like this. What's the way to works with references in mobx?
I would like to use links so I can:

```
user.payment['doSomething']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The great thing with mobx is what you can store links in observable. All you need is init them.

```
const user = new User
const payment = new Payment
user.payment = payment
payment.user = user
```

Now you can do `user.payment.value = 'newVal'`
Just make sure property payment inside user and property user inside payment are `@observable`